# Create Table fails because it is being used by active queries in this session

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, database-partitioning, liquibase-sql, table-partitioning

I am trying to implement dynamic partitioning on a table by using triggers on insert of data.

Table:
property(record_uuid uuid NOT NULL, change timestamp NOT NULL, value VARCHAR(50), PRIMARY KEY(property_id, record_uuid, change)) PARTITION BY RANGE(change)
Default partition table:
property_default PARTITION OF property DEFAULT
Trigger:
TRIGGER property_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON property FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.property_insert_function();
Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION property_insert_function()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS '
DECLARE
    partition_date TEXT;
    partition_name TEXT;
    start_of_month TEXT;
    end_of_next_month TEXT;
BEGIN
    partition_date := to_char(NEW.change,''YYYY-MM'');
    partition_name := ''property_'' || partition_date;
    start_of_month := to_char((NEW.change),''YYYY-MM'') || ''-01'';
    end_of_next_month := to_char((NEW.change + interval ''1 month''),''YYYY-MM'') || ''-01'';
IF NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM   information_schema.tables 
     WHERE  table_name = partition_name) 
THEN
    RAISE NOTICE ''A partition has been created %'', partition_name;
    EXECUTE format(E''CREATE TABLE %I PARTITION OF property FOR VALUES FROM (%L) TO (%L)'', partition_name, start_of_month,end_of_next_month);
    
END IF;

EXECUTE format(''INSERT INTO %I (record_uuid, change, value) VALUES($1,$2,$3)'', partition_name) using NEW.record_uuid, NEW.change, NEW.value;

END;
'

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Problem:
When it tries to create the partitioned table property_*, it fails with the error:
`ERROR  --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : **ERROR: cannot CREATE TABLE .. PARTITION OF "property" because it is being used by active queries in this session Where: SQL statement "CREATE TABLE "property_2023-06" PARTITION OF property FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-06-01') TO ('2023-07-01')" PL/pgSQL function property_insert_function() line 18 at EXECUTE**`

Default partition table already exists, I am not sure how I can achieve dynamic partitioning at the time of data insertion.